# C# HtmlAgilityPack - GetAttributeValue returning false bool

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm having trouble with the HtmlAgilityPack and the GetAttributeValue method.

In the code below, I'm expecting that my GetAttributeValue test for "href" will fail only on the html element without the attribute, however, it returns false on all elements.

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <a href=""http://www.google.com"" title=""Google"" />
            <a id=""someotherlink"" title=""Some Other Title"" />
        </body>
        </html> ";
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
        foreach (var link in node)
        {
            if (link.HasAttributes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(link.OuterHtml);
                if (link.GetAttributeValue("href", false))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + link.Attributes["href"].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tThis link don't have a href dude");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The doco states that GetAttributeValue should only return the false value when the value is not found.  Strangely enough, if I use the string , string signature, it works fine.

Doco at  https://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v400/html/211ece6d-1ae3-7c29-b86f-e908e4766d4c.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's because the value of attribute is `string` not a `boolean` and `AgilityPack` won't let you to convert that `string` to `false`.

By the way you can use Linq expression instead of `GetAttributeValue`

```
if (link.Attributes.Any(x => x.Name.Equals("href")))
```

Comment: The linq expression seems to be the way to go.  I see what you’re think with the attribute  value being a string, because it is, however the signature for GetAttributeValue should support this usage .

Comment: The signature is...
 `public bool GetAttributeValue(
 string name,
 bool def
) `

Comment: Dont know why but that signature is working for attributes which values can set to ```true``` eg. ```hidden="true"```

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlAgilityPack` [contains](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.cs) four methods:

1. `public string GetAttributeValue(string name, string def)`
2. `public int GetAttributeValue(string name, int def)`
3. `public bool GetAttributeValue(string name, bool def)`

[Added in 2020](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/365):

4. `public T GetAttributeValue<T>(string name, T def)`

**In the third case** (your question was asked in 2019, at that time there was no fourth option), the method converts the attribute value to boolean:

```
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(att.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return def;
    }
```

Method `Convert.ToBoolean` [converts a string to Boolean if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean#system-convert-toboolean(system-string)) the string contains the string `True` or string `False` (method ignores case as well as leading and trailing white space).

If the string contains other text, an exception is thrown and the `GetAttributeValue` method returns the default value `def`.

On
`<a href=""http://www.google.com"" title=""Google"" />`
method will try to convert string `http://www.google.com` to Boolean, throws an exception and returns `def` that is equal to `False`.

On `<a id=""someotherlink"" title=""Some Other Title"" />` (and other HTML elements without `href`) method returns `def` that is equal to `False`.

**In the first case** the method simply returns the attribute value:

```
return att.Value;
```

thus method with string signature works fine for you.